# How to iterate through a list of tuples containing three pair values?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to remove the tuple from the list whose first elements are the same since I am treating the letter pairs as having the same value despite their ordering. Here is the list I am trying to iterate through, called `tuples2`:

```
[(3, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'C', 'A'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (2, 'C', 'B'), (1, 'A', 'B'), (1, 'B', 'A')]
```

My current code:

```
for i in list(tuples2):
    if i[0] == i+1[0]:
        tuples2.remove(i)
    print tuples2
```

...Is throwing this error:

```
line 6: if i[0] == (i+1)[0]: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

How should I modify my code to account for this if I wanted to end up with
`[(3, 'A', 'C'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (1, 'A', 'B')]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of red-flags in this code. You should not be modifying a list that you are iterating over, that will cause you stop skip over items. *EDIT* I now see that you copied the list in your for-loop, but still, the following approach is a bit more safe. You can iterate backwards, but it's probably easier to build a *new* list. A straightforward way is to keep track of already-seen first elements, and only add if you haven't seen the first element before:

```
In [1]: data = [(3, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'C', 'A'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (2, 'C', 'B'), (1, 'A', 'B'), (1, 'B', 'A')]
   ...:
In [2]: seen = set()

In [3]: new_data = []
   ...: for triple in data:
   ...:     first = triple[0]
   ...:     if first in seen:
   ...:         continue
   ...:     seen.add(first)
   ...:     new_data.append(triple)
   ...:

In [4]: new_data
Out[4]: [(3, 'A', 'C'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (1, 'A', 'B')]
```

Using `.remove` is very inefficient. It changes your algorithm into O(n^2) rather than O(n).

Comment: Thank you so very much, this was super straightforward to do and works perfectly. I really appreciate your help! Keeping track of already-seen elements in that manner was exactly what I needed to do

Answer (score 3):

You have a false concept of the iteration of `i in list(tuples2)` : Using this syntax, i is not a index but actually the tuple itself. So, you can't do `i+1[0]`.

First, I recommend you do:

```
tuples_list = list(tuples2)
```

To solve this, you can use the `xrange` that python suggests (or `range`) that will work by index:

```
for i in xrange(len(tuples_list)-1):
    if tuples_list[i][0] == tuples_list[i+1][0]:
        #Do what you want
```

Comment: Thanks, but its throwing "if tuples_list[i] == tuples_list[i+1]:
IndexError: list index out of range" when I do what you suggessted

Comment: @CoraColeman sorry, fixing it - the last iteration ofcourse causes it.

Answer (score 3):

You could read into a dictionary keyed by the first components and then read out the values:

```
tuples = [(3, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'C', 'A'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (2, 'C', 'B'), (1, 'A', 'B'), (1, 'B', 'A')]
d = {x:(x,y,z) for x,y,z in tuples}
tuples = list(d.values())
```

Resulting `tuples`:

```
[(1, 'B', 'A'), (2, 'C', 'B'), (3, 'C', 'A')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this also worked perfectly, however preserving the sorted order of my list is the answer I was hoping to reach and juanpa.arrivillaga showed this.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your question using `groupby` from `itertools` module like this way:

```
from itertools import groubpy

a = [(3, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'C', 'A'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (2, 'C', 'B'), (1, 'A', 'B'), (1, 'B', 'A')]
final = [list(v)[0] for _,v in groupby(sorted(a), lambda x: x[0])]

print(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> [(1, 'A', 'B'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (3, 'A', 'C')]
```

Otherwise, if you need the `final` list in the same order as you gave in your question, you can reverse it:

```
final = list(reversed(final))
# OR
#final = sorted(final, reverse = True)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> [(3, 'A', 'C'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (1, 'A', 'B')]
```

Comment: using `sorted` here only happens to work, and isn't generalizable.

Comment: I can also use `list(reversed(final))`.

Comment: I don't think so. I think `reversed`, again, only *happens* to work. When you sorted it at the beginning, you lost the ordering, so if the original list is not in some sort of sorted order, you won't be able to get it back.

Answer (score 2):

Just group by first element and take the first of each group.

```
>>> [next(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(tuples2, lambda x: x[0])]
[(3, 'A', 'C'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (1, 'A', 'B')]
```

Or even simpler:

```
>>> tuples2[::2]
[(3, 'A', 'C'), (2, 'B', 'C'), (1, 'A', 'B')]
```

Comment: I think actually in this particular case `tuples[::2]` is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**IMMEDIATE PROBLEM**

What is this supposed to mean?

```
i+1[0]
```

**i** is a tuple; you are trying to use **i** as both the index and the element.  The iteration you need is more like:

```
for i in range (len(tuples2)):
    if tuples2[i] == tuples2[i+1]:
```

... which still doesn't do the job.  This checks for equality of the entire tuple.  However, you say that all you care about is equality of the first element.  You would then want:

```
    if tuples2[i][0] == tuples2[i+1][0]:
```

This is in terms of your present code; others have shown you more "Pythonic" ways of doing this.

**GENERAL SOLUTION**

This code assumes that the other elements of the tuple are equal, that tuples with identical first elements are adjacent in the list, and that matching tuples come only in pairs.  Is it possible that your list will include something such as:

```
tuples2 = [(3, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'C', 'A'), 
           (2, 'B', 'C'), (2, 'C', 'B'), 
           (1, 'A', 'B'), (1, 'A', 'Z'), (1, 'B', 'A')]
```

With the additional 'Z' element perhaps being buried between the "3" elements?  Regardless, even if you sort the list, you get the "AZ" element between the other "1" elements.

If this is a problem for you, then I suggest that you first convert each tuple to a list, sorting the elements into order.  For instance, thi'bwould convert (1, 'B', 'A') to [1, 'A', 'B'].  Then use any of the given methods to eliminate duplicates, including the one you've already programmed.  I generally do this by turning things back into tuples and then forming a set -- which automatically eliminates duplicates.